# Google Cloud Domain restriction

Tags: networking, web, dns, web-deployment

I have hosted a testing domain say `https://example.com` on google cloud as a new project. But I want to restrict the access to this domain, only owner should be able to view this url in browser.
I followed a lot of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview) but was not to find the appropriate solution for this. Please help if this is possible to achieve.